# Voltage Difference Across Capacitor Plates

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, capacitance, conventions

If a parallel plate capacitor is connected to a 9V battery, what is the electric potential difference between the two plates? Is it 18V since the positive plate will have an electric potential of 9V and the negative plate -9V? Or is it just 9V?

Answer (score 1):

The 9V in "9V battery" typically refers to it's emf, and this would be the potential difference between its ends. Since the potential is defined up to an arbitrary constant, it could mean that the potentials at the ends could be $V_+ = 9V$ and $V_- = 0V$ or $V_+ = 18V$ and $V_- = 9V$, etc; the potential *difference* $\Delta V = V_+ - V_-$ will always be $9V$.

If the capacitor is connected to this battery with wires, then all of this potential difference will appear (eventually in the case of wires with a nonzero resistance, or immediately if resistance-less) across the plates of the capacitor according to the [loop rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_voltage_law), so the potential difference would typically be $9V$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a ton!